# cannot receive json data in android

Tags: php, android, json

this is the php code i am using to retrieve data from my database

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("employee tracking");
$p = "pass";
$query="select password from user_login where user_login.E_ID=" . $_POST['EID'];
$sql=mysql_query($query);
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
$output[]=$row;
print(json_encode($output));
mysql_close();
?>
```

this is the android code

```
private class myClass extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Long> {
        String url = "http://192.168.164.1/dbLogin.php";
        @Override
        protected Long doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Log.d("Debug", "Valid");
            int sc;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
             HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
             HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, TIMEOUT_MILLISEC);
             HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, TIMEOUT_MILLISEC);
            DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);
            HttpPost httpGet = new HttpPost(url);
            try {
                ArrayList<NameValuePair> vp = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                Log.d("Parameter", params[1]);
                vp.add( new BasicNameValuePair("EID", params[0]) );
                httpGet.setEntity((new UrlEncodedFormEntity(vp)));
                BasicHttpResponse res = (BasicHttpResponse) client.execute(httpGet);
                Log.v("response code", res.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() + ""); 
                StatusLine sl = res.getStatusLine();
                sc = sl.getStatusCode();
                Log.d("Status", Integer.toString(sc));
                if( sc == 200 ) {

                    HttpEntity entity = res.getEntity();
                    InputStream is = entity.getContent();
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( is ) );
                    String line ;
                    while( ( line = reader.readLine()) != null  ) {
                        sb.append(line);
                    }

                    Log.d("Out", sb.toString() );   
                    String checkString = sb.toString();
                    int cur = 0;
                    while( checkString.charAt(cur) != ':' ) cur ++;
                    cur += 2 ;
                    String pass = "";
                    while( checkString.charAt(cur) != '"') {
                        pass += checkString.charAt(cur);
                        cur ++;
                    }

                    if( pass.equals(params[1])) {
                        Intent ourIntent = new Intent("com.employeetracking.project.MENU");
                        startActivity(ourIntent);
                    }

                }

            } catch( Exception e ) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

    }
```

The problem i am facing is that the above codes gives the correct result when run on the emulator. But when running the application on android the data is not retrieved. I am using android to connect to the database in my laptop via wi-fi. Can anyone please help me to figure of the problem . Thanks.

Comment: Be sure to connect your Android phone to the same wi-fi network than your laptop. Also, check if 192.168.4.1 is available for external connections, give it a try on the 80 port.

Comment: try this: `String url = "http://10.0.2.2/dbLogin.php";`

Comment: i connected my phone to my laptop using a hotspot and i can send data from my phone to my database but cannot receive any data . and i used http://10.0.2.2/dbLogin.php as the url while testing in the emulator which works fine.

Comment: so have you solved your problem ?

Comment: Just a quick heads up: line 4 of your php script if vulnerable to SQL injection

Comment: no i did not solve the problem . what i meant was the program runs fine on the emulator but does not work when run on the android phone.

Answer (score 0):

as you are using your local server

use **IP= 10.0.2.2**

```
String url = "http://10.0.2.2/dbLogin.php";
```

This will allow you to access your local server in **Android Emulator**

Hope you get your answer.

Comment: before running the program on my device i tested using the emulator and used the ip 10.0.2.2 and could receive the data from the localhost server. i am using xampp on my laptop as a server and i have uploaded the database there. i can also input data in my database using my phone. but the problem occurs when i try to retrieve the data. the program seems to get stuck at this line :

BasicHttpResponse res = (BasicHttpResponse) client.execute(httpGet);